# Using WordPress for large collaborative site

Tags: security, wordpress, site-maintenance

I work for a government agency, and we're thinking about creating a new, fairly large site using WordPress as the platform. It would involve allowing quite a few people around the state access to the site as editors, bringing together an even larger pool of content creators.

This is the first site like this I've created/run, although I feel solid on the basics of WordPress. What should I watch out for in terms of setup, maintenance, hosting, security etc.? I'm hoping to talk with some WordPress veterans to figure out the questions I haven't already asked myself, you know? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Wordpress page on [User Roles](http://en.support.wordpress.com/user-roles/) it defines what each role can do:

> There are four roles for users that you wish to add to your blog: Administrator, Editor, Author, and Contributor.
>
> **Important**: Please be careful of the roles you give users on your blog. If you add a user as an administrator, you are granting full ownership rights to him/her. This means that if he/she deletes the blog and/or its content, there is no wrongdoing. For this reason, we recommend having only one administrator per blog

For a full description of the roles see the help page.

If possible assign people to the lowest level role possible, don't be tempted to make everyone an editor for example.

The fewer people there are with rights to make large and permanent changes the less chance there is that they'll get in each other's way.

Answer (score 1):

There are many large sites running Wordpress.

Setup is a breeze.

Maintenance (bugs and security) is taken care of by the Wordpress community.

Make sure to get a good caching add on. These make a big difference.

Security however is a downside. Lately (last couple months) many sites have been hacked.I am not sure how large of concern this is, but it could be a problem.